# Unknown structure in java 1.6

Tags: java, java-6, legacy-code, legacy-app

i'm working on a legacy project & i found something like that :

```
test:{
        if(1 == 1) {
            System.out.println("Oups");
            break test;
        }
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
```

I google it, but nothing seems to match with this kind of structure.

Of course, this part of code compile & run ... ????

Do someone know what that do ?

Comment: `test:` is called a label. Just like on a loop, the `break` jumps to the end of a block. While it works, labels are generally too confusing, partly because they are rarely used, so I would avoid them. This has been part of Java since version 1.0 and is still supported in Java 10.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: I don't know for Java, but the .NET framework internal implementation uses a lot of labels.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: okay, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jump-out label ([Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html)):

```
label: for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        if (something(i, j)) break label; // jumps out of the i loop
    }
} 
// i.e. jumps to here
```

Answer (score 0):

`test:` is called a label. Just like on a loop, the `break` jumps to the end of a block. The label is used to define where the break jumps to. Note the start of the scope doesn't mater provided the end is where you need it to be so really you are labelling the end not the start of the code to break to.

While it works, labels are generally too confusing with `if` statements, partly because they are rarely used, so I would avoid them. If you can write something with a label, you can usually write it without by using a method or in this case using an `else` to the `if`

Even using labels with loops should be avoided if you can.

This has been part of Java since version 1.0 and is still supported in Java 10.

Comment: Why ain't it a duplicate of that linked question?

Comment: @ThomasWeller The linked question doesn't illustrate what the `break` does.

Comment: @ThomasWeller `break` is merely incidental to the question, which is entitled "Unknown *structure*"; if it didn't have `break` in it, would it also not be a duplicate because it has `if` in it?

Comment: @GeorgeJempty The `break` is essential to this structure and it doesn't make sense without it.

Answer (score 0):

It is called `label`.

It is used with `break` to do something similar to `goto` in other languages.

More details you can find [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html)

Answer (score -2):

As comments already said, this is a label that break can jump to / out of. More information here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html